# Excel VBA Application.OnTime. Can I pass a time value to it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an macro that runs and stops fine based on a button click, but I wanted to add the ability to automatically stop the "start click" at a time set in an excel field that would be adjustable by the user.
I cannot find any details around being able to pass a time in from and excel field say E4 in this case to the OnTime function.   I don't want to hard code a time as it could change on when I want the `Button1_Click` to stop.   Any ideas?

```
 Sub StopApp()
    Dim timeout As Date
    endtime = Sheets("MAIN").Range("E4").value
    Application.OnTime TimeValue(endtime), Procedure:="Button1_Click", Schedule:=False
    MsgBox "App has Stopped"
    Sheets("MAIN").Range("B1").value = "DISCONNECTED"
 End Sub
```

Comment: What is in Range("E4").value? Is it a real time or real datetime or a string?

Comment: It is Time format 12:30:55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TimeValue converts text-that-looks-like-time into real time. It doesn't work well turning real time into time.

```
Application.OnTime endtime, Procedure:="Button1_Click", Schedule:=False
```

You may want/need to include the current date. Typically, OnTime is launched on a datetime, not a time.

```
Application.OnTime Date + endtime, Procedure:="Button1_Click", Schedule:=False
```

Date + endtime may have to be Date + endtime - int(endtime < time) to run OnTime tomorrow if the scheduled time is earlier than now.